# db seeds from a package Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, seeding

I am developing a package for an application with Laravel 4, I added some seeders into the folder seeds of folder database of my application, what is the right command line to run the seeder ?

I tried some similar commands to db:migrate to run these seeders like:

```
 php artisan db:seed --package=Packagename/PackageDirectory
```

but it seems they are not working here, what is the right command line to run these seeders insdie the package from root of application?

Comment: Do you get any errors or output when you run the command?

Comment: Are you in the right environment?

Comment: @Jerodev RunTimeException The "--package" option does not exist. this is the error I get

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#database-seeding), the only available option for this function is `--class`.

What you can do is create a class that gets data from your package.